# highcharts minPointLength do not work for unstacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, highcharts

I am working with an unstacked bar chart when the data is all zero. The yAxis in the middle is a straight line when the data length smaller than or equal to 4, when the data length is bigger than four the yAxis become a dashed line. If I add 'stacking': normal to the series to make the bar chart a stacked bar chart, the yAxis is always a straight line. See the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/junkainiu/u6sgyxL6/5/

**html**

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

**js**

`$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [0,0,0,0],
            stacking: 'normal'
        }]
    });
});`

and

http://jsfiddle.net/junkainiu/bz22h3eb/7/

**html**

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

**js**

`$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [0,0,0,0,0],
        }]
    });
});`

to see the difference. In highcharts, the default minPointLength is zero, but it doesn't seem to work in unstacked bar charts. So I would like to make the yAxis a straight line no matter it is a stacked chart or unstacked chart. Is there a way to do this？ Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key problem here is that the gaps are caused by the empty bars. It seems that Highcharts is trying to show the 0 value bars, even though they should be invisible.

Try setting a plot band to draw a solid line along the base of the y-axis:

```
yAxis: {
    plotBands: {
        from: 0, to: 0, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#CCCCCC', zIndex: 10
    }
},
```

You can to set the band to go from 0 to 0 and set the border width so it effectively becomes a line. The `zIndex` property will ensure that it stays above the gaps.

This will remove those gaps along your axis line (see an updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/bz22h3eb/11/).

> **Note:** The attribute `plotLines` will achieve the same effect, however, that will cause a type error (`(d.plotLines || []).concat is not a function`) once you start to define data for the bars. It seems `plotLines` is meant for line and spline charts!

Here's a screenshot of the edited chart:

[image]

Does this help to solve your issue?

Comment: This can remove the gaps, but will make the highcharts do not show the series when there is data.

Comment: You're right: I'm getting a type error `(d.plotLines || []).concat is not a function`. That's odd! Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Ah! I see! For bar charts, I need `plotBands`, not `plotLines`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The plotBands seems can not remove the gaps

Comment: Check the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/bz22h3eb/10/. Do you see gaps in this version? If so, which browser are you using?

Comment: yes, there is still gaps. My browser is chrome Version 50.0.2661.94 m

Comment: I saw the issue in Firefox as well, so I made a few new changes. I realized that the gaps are due to the bars ... even though they have a value of 0, Highcharts is still drawing *something*. I added a `zIndex` value of 10 to force the plot band above those gaps. See my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/bz22h3eb/11/

Comment: Works perfectly!That's exactly what I need!

Comment: @JunkaiNiu That's awesome! I'm so glad to have solved this for you.